# Can independent movies/short films made by film makers be listed as video.movie object?

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

According to Facebook's guidelines it states :

> Please note that the video.movie object is reserved only for full-length, feature films 
>   (i.e. not to be used with movie trailers, movie clips, user-generated video content, etc.).
>
> > Source : http://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/guides/video.watches/#criteria

I am building a website that would be a platform for short film and independent movie makers to list their movies. Can I list those films as a video.movie object ? My confusion is in the word "full-length". Does "full-length" mean "not clips" or "full-length" means a movie playing for 1 or 2 hours ? Please clarify.